# What is the purpose of dialer's control function?

Tags: go, networking

I am currently studying network programming in Go.

Currently, a timeout test using the deadline of the context is in progress by myself.

```golang
package socket

import (
    "context"
    "net"
    "syscall"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestDialContext(t *testing.T) {
    deadline := time.Now().Add(time.Second * 5)
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), deadline)
    defer cancelFunc()

    var dialer net.Dialer
    dialer.Control = func(_, _ string, _ syscall.RawConn) error {
        time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
        return nil
    }
    conn, err := dialer.DialContext(ctx, "tcp", "10.0.0.0:http")
    if err == nil {
        conn.Close()
        t.Fatal("expected no connection")
    }
    if nErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nErr.Timeout() {
        t.Logf("expected timeout error: %v", err)
    } else {
        t.Errorf("expected timeout error; actual: %v", err)
    }
    if ctx.Err() != context.DeadlineExceeded {
        t.Errorf("expected deadline exceeded; actual: %v", ctx.Err())
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, I tried to connect using a context with a 5-second deadline.

In addition, by using the dialer's control function when requested, the control function is called immediately after being connected (actually right before being connected), so that a nil error is returned after 4 seconds.

By my intent, this test should fail. The reason is that the control function returns a nil error before the deadline of 5 seconds is reached.

But the test succeeds as below.

```bash
=== RUN   TestDialContext
    dial_context_test.go:27: expected timeout error: dial tcp 10.0.0.0:80: i/o timeout
--- PASS: TestDialContext (5.01s)
PASS
```

What exactly is the purpose of the control function? Is the error returned by the control function unrelated to the error returned by the `net.Dial()` function? Is the test using the control function like the code I wrote meaningless?

Thanks for reading this long question!

Comment: Presumably no server is listening on 10.0.0.0:80 (or it is firewalled). Just because Control doesn't return an error that doesn't mean establishing the connection succeeds. To make the test reliable start a TCP server on the loopback interface and connect to that.

Comment: @Peter 

I'm sorry. I now know that the nil error returned by the control function has no effect on dialing. I wanted to test when the connection was successful 5 seconds ago. You mean to say that normal testing is only possible when a request is sent to a server that allows a successful connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly is the purpose of the control function?

To give the dialing code a chance to call functions on the socket's underlying file descriptor — e.g. one of the [syscall.Setsockopt](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#SetsockoptByte) functions — after the socket is created and before the connection is established.

> Is the error returned by the control function unrelated to the error returned by the `net.Dial()` function?

If the control function returns an error, then dialing fails with that error. If the control function returns a nil error, then dialing continues as usual.

> Is the test using the control function like the code I wrote meaningless?

Pretty much. Your control function sleeps 4 seconds but otherwise doesn't do anything.

Comment: I understood that if I return nil from the Control function, dialing continues.
But if it succeeds in connecting to the server, err will return nil. So, what error should I raise in the Control function to test that the connection to the server was successful?

Comment: @didnlie23 nothing. The idea doesn't work. If you return an error in the Control function, connecting is never attempted, so how could it be successful?